# CharField choices for different ContentType

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, django-models

Suppose I have this model :

```
class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    sub_type = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES)
```

and

```
CHOICES = [(a, A),(b, B), ...]
```

is there a way to exclude some choices depending on the ContentType involved ?

Comment: There are several ways, depending how you need to restrict these choices. Is it through a form or another way ?

Comment: @May Actually I was hoping to do this at the database level before insertion.

Comment: Well you could use django's `pre_save` signal to check instance content_type or override the save method of the model and insert your logic to restrict `self.CHOICES`.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I am looking for ! Will accept this as an answer if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the save method is probably the best way to go (other signals), see related doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).
Try something like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.content_type: # your logic
    self.CHOICES = restricted_choices
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```